# Sort rails collection_select dropdown field by foreign attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I've got a collection_select and I want to sort it.
usually no problem, just pass a `collection.order(name DESC)` or whatever to do that into the collection_select's collection field.

Unfortunately, my sort criteria is a foreign attribute, something like that:
(saying we've got a posts and an author model, and I want to sort the posts by the authors name)

```
f.collection_select(:post, :post_id, Posts.order(author.name DESC), :id, :post_with_author_name_as_prefix)
```

...which of course does not work.

(post_with_author_name_as_prefix, the text method,  would be a virtual method inside the posts model returning something like "John Doe: Random thoughts", which actually is the reason for that sort criteria...)

Any thougts how to get around that without big joins, db views and stuff like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a `Post` belongs to an `Author`, you can do this:

```
Post.joins(:author).order("authors.name DESC")
```

You should probably give it a name and make it part of the `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  scope :ordered_by_author, -> { joins(:author).order("authors.name DESC") }
  ...
end
```

And use in the view:

```
<%= f.collection_select :post_id, Post.ordered_by_author, :id, :post_with_author_name_as_prefix %>
```